# Creating a variable row table from pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-tables

struggling Excel user here. I think the below is likely relatively simple athough I am struggling to phrase the question, and therefore can't find answers online.

I have a list of names from a Pivot table, I am wanting to transfer these names to a Table 2 with additional and variable rows under each name for their projects. My first issue is as as follows

1. Transfer list of Pivot Table names to a new column with variable row spacing on Table 2. I have about 300 names so would prefer to not have to do this manually. Users may also add additional project rows as required.

[image: List of names from Pivot Table]
[image: Desired Table 2 output]

Then, if the above is possible, I would like to achieve the following

2. When users are removed from the Pivot Table, update Table 2 to have their name, and associated project rows deleted.

I greatly appreciate any assistance with this.

Kind regards,
Lee

I have tried the Excel "Group" function.
I have tried adding the manually added project data direct into the pivot table.
I have tried "quick analysis"

Comment: What is the source for the name data in the PT and the data that associates the projects with the PT names?